# Number of structures which can be formed from building blocks

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I was seeing my nephew's building block toy set today and a mathematical question struck me: How many structures could I form from by stacking these blocks?

For simplicity sake, I've considered only three specific types of blocks from the total set:
[image]

The first type,  it is tridentate at the top and can be bitten at three slots on the bottom.

The second type, it is bidentate at the top and cane be bitten at two slots on the bottom.

The third type, it is unidate at the top and can be bitten at one slot on the bottom.

Suppose I have $p$ of the first type, $q$ of the second type and $r$ of the third type. Let the recursion function which takes in the number of types and counts the total structures be $F_{p,q,r}$. Observations of the function:

1. $$ F_{p,0,0} = F_{0,p,0}= F_{0,0,p} $$
2. $$  F(0,0,0) =  0$$
3. $$F_{0,0,r+1}= F_{0,0,r} + 1$$
4. $$F_{p+1,0,0}  = F_{p,0,0}  + 1$$
5. $$F_{0,q,r} = \sum_{(s,t), 2s+t = r}  F_{0,q+s,t }$$
6. $$ F_{p,0,r } = \sum_{(u,v,w), 3u + 2v +w = r} F_{p+u,v,w} $$

In observation (5), (6), I note that the $(s,t)$ pair and $(u,v,w)$  triplet being summed over all integer solutions of corresponding equation give the structures again.

Intuitively the split means take the unidentate blocks and make them into double blocks by gluing two sides in (5), and in (6) it means to consider gluing two form bidentate and tridentate blocks.

Any hints on how I can proceed and finish this problem

Comment: F(0,0,0)=1. This is a common degenerate case in recurrence relations.

Comment: How would you argue that it should be that one over $F(0,0,0)=0$? @Trebor

Comment: @Buraian Because there's exactly one way to not make anything, as opposed to their being 0 ways to not make anything (it's clearly possible to not make anything, so $F(0,0,0) \geq 1$.

Comment: Alright, I've edited the question accordingly @BrandonduPreez

Comment: I don't find your question very clear. The spatial arrangement of the blocks is very important, but you don't seem to be taking that into account. If you arrange two $2\times 1$ blocks into a $4\times 1$ line then the number of possibilities for what you can do next is not the same as if you arrange them into a $2\times 2$ square.

Comment: I haven't accounted for the gluing procedure of keeping block side by side, Ican keep only on top. The gluing thing I had mentioned in the question is just an intuition for equation the counting functionsatisfies